# Magento 2 error - Class 'Vendor\Sales\Model\Order\Email\ScopeInterface' not found in

Tags: magento2, class

```
use Vendor\Sales\Helper\Data;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface;
use Magento\Payment\Helper\Data as PaymentHelper;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address\Renderer;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Container\OrderIdentity;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Container\Template;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender;
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order as OrderResource;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;

class OrderSender extends \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender
{
    const FREE_PICKUP_SHIPPING_METHOD = 'freeshipping_freeshipping';
    const XML_PATH_EMAIL_LA_PICKUP_TEMPLATE      = 'sales_email/order/flatrate32_pickup_template';

    /**
     * @var Data
     */
    protected $helper;

    /**
     * @var PaymentHelper
     */
    protected $paymentHelper;

    /**
     * @var OrderResource
     */
    protected $orderResource;

    /**
     * Global configuration storage.
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    protected $globalConfig;

    /**
     * @var Renderer
     */
    protected $addressRenderer;

    /**
     * Application Event Dispatcher
     *
     * @var ManagerInterface
     */
    protected $eventManager;

    /**
     * @var ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    protected $config;

    /**
     * @param Template $templateContainer
     * @param OrderIdentity $identityContainer
     * @param Order\Email\SenderBuilderFactory $senderBuilderFactory
     * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
     * @param Renderer $addressRenderer
     * @param PaymentHelper $paymentHelper
     * @param OrderResource $orderResource
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $globalConfig
     * @param ManagerInterface $eventManager
     * @param \Vendor\Segment\Helper\Data $helper
     * @param ScopeConfigInterface $config
     */
    public function __construct(
        Template $templateContainer,
        OrderIdentity $identityContainer,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\SenderBuilderFactory $senderBuilderFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        Renderer $addressRenderer,
        PaymentHelper $paymentHelper,
        OrderResource $orderResource,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $globalConfig,
        ManagerInterface $eventManager,
        Data $helper,
        ScopeConfigInterface $config
    ) {
        $this->paymentHelper        = $paymentHelper;
        $this->orderResource        = $orderResource;
        $this->globalConfig         = $globalConfig;
        $this->addressRenderer      = $addressRenderer;
        $this->eventManager         = $eventManager;
        $this->identityContainer    = $identityContainer;
        $this->templateContainer    = $templateContainer;
        $this->senderBuilderFactory = $senderBuilderFactory;
        $this->logger               = $logger;
        $this->helper               = $helper;
        $this->config               = $config;
    }


    /**
     * Get config path
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getConfig($path, $storeId = null)
    {
        return $this->config->getValue($path, ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE); // error appear here
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check with below code.

```
use Vendor\Sales\Helper\Data;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface;
use Magento\Payment\Helper\Data as PaymentHelper;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address\Renderer;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Container\OrderIdentity;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Container\Template;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender;
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order as OrderResource;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;

class OrderSender extends \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender
{
const FREE_PICKUP_SHIPPING_METHOD = 'freeshipping_freeshipping';
const XML_PATH_EMAIL_LA_PICKUP_TEMPLATE      = 'sales_email/order/flatrate32_pickup_template';

/**
 * @var Data
 */
protected $helper;

/**
 * @var PaymentHelper
 */
protected $paymentHelper;

/**
 * @var OrderResource
 */
protected $orderResource;

/**
 * @var Renderer
 */
protected $addressRenderer;

/**
 * Application Event Dispatcher
 *
 * @var ManagerInterface
 */
protected $eventManager;

/**
 * @var ScopeConfigInterface
 */
protected $config;

/**
 * @param Template $templateContainer
 * @param OrderIdentity $identityContainer
 * @param Order\Email\SenderBuilderFactory $senderBuilderFactory
 * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
 * @param Renderer $addressRenderer
 * @param PaymentHelper $paymentHelper
 * @param OrderResource $orderResource
 * @param ManagerInterface $eventManager
 * @param \Vendor\Segment\Helper\Data $helper
 * @param ScopeConfigInterface $config
 */
public function __construct(
    Template $templateContainer,
    OrderIdentity $identityContainer,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\SenderBuilderFactory $senderBuilderFactory,
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
    Renderer $addressRenderer,
    PaymentHelper $paymentHelper,
    OrderResource $orderResource,
    ManagerInterface $eventManager,
    Data $helper,
    ScopeConfigInterface $config
) {
    $this->paymentHelper        = $paymentHelper;
    $this->orderResource        = $orderResource;
    $this->addressRenderer      = $addressRenderer;
    $this->eventManager         = $eventManager;
    $this->identityContainer    = $identityContainer;
    $this->templateContainer    = $templateContainer;
    $this->senderBuilderFactory = $senderBuilderFactory;
    $this->logger               = $logger;
    $this->helper               = $helper;
    $this->config               = $config;
}


/**
 * Get config path
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getConfig($path, $storeId = null)
{
    return $this->config->getValue($path, \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't define **ScopeInterface** but used in the below function. Please change the below method.

**From:**

```
public function getConfig($path, $storeId = null)
{
    return $this->config->getValue($path, ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
}
```

**To:**

```
public function getConfig($path, $storeId = null)
{
    return $this->config->getValue($path, \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
}
```